# How to call PHP api from C# ?(simple example)

Tags: c#, .net, php, api

So I need a very basic interaction example of C# client using some PHP API (A remote service being called from a C# app). I want to see a simple php API containing 2 methods sum(a, b):c and echo(string):string and a simple C# client able to use that methods. How to do such thing?

Comment: What do you mean by PHP API exactly? A remote service being called from a C# app? A c# APP using PHP calls inside the application?

Comment: A remote service being called from a C# app

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by a PHP server but can't you write a script that will add two numbers:

```
<?php echo (int)$_GET["a"] + (int)$_GET["b"]; ?>
```

And in C#:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var a = 50;
    var b = 100;
    var result = client.DownloadString(string.Format("http://example.com/add.php?a={0}&b={1}", a, b));
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Another and a better option is [PHP SOAP](http://developer.apple.com/internet/webservices/soapphp.html).

Comment: look like your PHP SOAP link is dead

Answer (score 1):

Create a PHP web service and a C# client defining a proxy to call it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(VS.80).aspx) Class